# What can I do to fix the volume button back onto my Moto M?

Tags: hardware, volume-control, buttons

Heres a set of pictures depicting the problem.

[image: This paer is of the volume button]

[image: A side view]

***Any form of help will be much appreciated !!!***

Comment: See this https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Motorola+Moto+G+1st+Generation+Power+and+Volume+Buttons+Replacement/30931

Comment: im sorry, but this is a single piece phone(not sure if thats the right term) ie, cant be opened. COuld you please suggest some other way? @beeshyams

Comment: I guess service centre is the only way out IMO

Comment: There does not appear to be aftermarket/3rd party parts, instructions, or tear-down tutorials for this device yet. That would mean your only recourse is to take it to an Authorized Moto/Lenovo service center for repair.

Comment: a cell phone repair shop is probably the cheapest option other then doing it yourself assuming they can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to **take the phone to an** [**Authorised Motorola Service Center**](https://www.google.com/search?q=motorola%20repair%20centre) to get it repaired, but it may be possible to *attempt it yourself.*

As there are no iFixIt guides available currently, your only other option would be to refer to <strike>videos</strike> a video on YouTube, where the screws on the bottom of the phone are removed to access the internals (and volume button)

[**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CmvQPpTgfc**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CmvQPpTgfc)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't try to fix user self-take it to the service center and make it be fixed because if you fix it won't be the longer best way is to take it to the customer service center.